# SLElement doesn't exist xCode 5.1

Tags: subliminal

I have a button inside of a UITableView.  The UITableView was created in storyboard, but the button was created pragmatically.  I get:

Unexpected exception occurred ***SLUIAElementInvalidException*** for reason: Element '<SLButton description:"Add Memberin">' does not exist.

when I try to "tap" the button element:

```
SLButton *addMemberButton = [SLButton elementWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Add Member"];
SLLog(@"%@", addMemberButton); // prints <SLButton description:"Add Member">
[addMemberButton tap];
```

I have the following code in viewDidLoad in the viewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.addMemberButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    self.addMemberButton.accessibilityValue  = @"Add Member";
    self.addMemberButton.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton;
}
```

When I use the accessibility inspector, the button is accessible and has the label I created.
I even tried turning off accessibility in the UITableView with:

```
self.tableView.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
self.tableView.accessibilityLabel = nil;
```

This made no difference.  Any insights as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to match the button by label, but "Add Member" is actually the button's *value*.

`SLButton *addMemberButton = [SLButton elementWithAccessibilityLabel:nil value:@"Add Member" traits:UIAccessibilityTraitButton];`

should work instead, though I think it would be more appropriate to set "Add Member" as the label (see the description of `accessibilityLabel` vs. `accessibilityValue` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/accessibilityLabel), as well as the guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW6)).

If "Add Member" is the button's title, you actually don't need to set any properties manually--buttons automatically derive their accessibility labels from their titles.